# Very wide range high voltage measurement with optical isolation

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, measurement, opto-isolator

I have a voltage source I'd like to measure, it is from 0V to 1kV, any value in that range. The accuracy isn't that important, but measuring with an accuracy with 1-5% would be perfect. This has to be then optically isolated, so I could read the voltage on a microcontroller. The second part is not hard at all, when using regular optoisolators. The problem is scaling the voltage down so that I can light up the diode of the optoisolator, and keeping the results semi-linear or semi-logarithmic so I could calculate the output voltage. Is using voltage dividers with a diode the only available option? With such a wide input voltage range getting good results with that method is not possible, because the voltage defines what resistor types and values to use. Any advice?

Comment: Why not put the ADC on the high-voltage side?

Comment: Is the voltage measurement a differential type ie the source is floating?

Comment: I am switching an IGBT with the load being on the low-side. I want to measure the drop on the load, and see its behaviour to model it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're REALLY careful with your choice of parts, you can resistively divide the 1kV input into something you can read directly.  It won't be isolated that way, so you'd need to figure out some kind of protection in case a resistor comes loose or you drop a wire across it or something like that.  Maybe a sacrificial buffer amp?

If you use an active buffer between the source and the ADC, you can also apply some gain and offset so that the expected range to measure fills up the entire range of the ADC (with some headroom for out-of-range detection).  That might be a good idea by itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you scale your 1kV down to something manageable, you could then use it as the input to a voltage-to-frequency converter on the HV side. Then take the output of the VFC to your opto-isolator as a simple digital pulse-train. On the other side of your opto, use your microcontroller to do a frequency measurement.

If you prefer to stay in the analog domain, then you could try a 'linear optocoupler' like a Vishay IL300. Internally it has 1 emitter and 2 matched detectors, and you use the output of one of the detectors to linearise the output of the other one.

Comment: IL300 is a somewhat generic part IIRC; at least Siemens and TI make their own too; the latter is called TIL300. I don't know who came up with it originally.

Comment: Turns out that Vishay has bought Infineon's (iteself spun off from Siemens) IR division circa 2002, so that's how they ended up with the IL300. TI has discontinued their TIL300.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use resistor divider to scale down, and then isolation amplifier. Simple ones are available from TI. Then use your MCU's ADC.

Alternatively you can use some simple I2C or SPI ADC and isolate it's communication channel. This way you will use standard and interchangeable parts.

Last option i can see is linear optocouplers. Personally i really don't like them.

Answer (score 0):

This will be crude, but you could measure the photo-current from an LED.

(HV->resistor->led-> PD->current.)

The light is fairly linear with current above 1mA or so... below that you'd have to measure the LED.  (it's like a 3/2 power law or something.)  Here's a plot,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/atyo4uvsb09fgd7/LED-PD.BMP?dl=0

But it would be easy to do a few calibration points (with low voltage and smaller resistor)

For the current measurement my DMM has a uA current range smallest digit is 10nA.

Comment: That can work, if you calibrate for the specific part that you're using.  They tend to have wide variations between parts, but they're pretty stable by themselves.  Also, 1mA at 1kV is 1W dissipated in the resistor.  Make sure you can handle that.

Comment: @AaronD, Oh I said it was crude.  Still, there's like 3-4 orders of magnitude over which you could do a single point calibration. I find the 3/2 power dependence interesting.  These leds are linear only over ~1 order of magnitude.  Above ~10 mA you start to see heating effects.  (I was thinking of grinding away some of the plastic on the bottom and getting a bigger heat sink next to the LED body.  (through hole parts, for those that didn't look up the part number.)

Comment: Careful about grinding away the case.  The specs depend on a light-tight enclosure.  And it's probably infrared so you can't see it directly to confirm that it's still okay.

Comment: @AaronD, Huh? Sorry, I was talking about grinding away the plastic on the led lead.  So I could keep the led die cooler, reduce the heating effects (no IR involved.) (Perhaps we are talking past each other. ?)

Comment: Is this a discrete solution?  I was thinking about a premade optocoupler in a 4-pin DIP package.

Comment: @AaronD, yeah I was thinking discrete.  Most opto's have transistor outputs.  Those with diodes make a string of them.  And what ever approach I agree you'd have to  measure/ calibrate the signal.  (I mostly use opto's with digital signals where you don't care as much about the exact ouptu voltage.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a linear optocoupler. Given your accuracy requirements the following circuit lifted from http://www.avagotech.com/docs/5954-8430E should be a good tradeoff (there are more sophisticated solutions, with more complex & costly schematics)

[image]

Claimed performance is as follows:

> Typical Performance of the
>   Wide Bandwidth AC Amplifier:
>
> • 2% linearity over 1 V p-p dynamic range
>
> • Unity voltage gain
>
> • 10 MHz bandwidth
>
> • Gain drift: –0.6% /°C
>
> • Common mode rejection: 22 dB at 1 MHz
>
> • 3000 V DC insulation

You still need a voltage divider, power supplies etc. to complete that. Regarding the divider, someone said above you need to be really careful (TM). Well, here's a part suggestion from R.B. Northrop's *Introduction to Instrumentation and Measurements* [3 ed.]

> An external resistive voltage divider probe is generally used to measure
>   DC voltages from 1 to 40 kV. Such a probe makes an external voltage divider with the DC
>   voltmeter’s input resistance. For example, the Fluke Model 80K-40 high-voltage probe is
>   designed to be used with any DC voltmeter having an input resistance of 10 MΩ. It makes
>   a 1000:1 voltage divider, so 1 kV applied to the probe gives 1 V at the meter. The probe and meter present a 1000 MΩ load to the high-voltage CUT [Circuit under test]; hence, the probe and meter draw 1 μA/kV from the CUT.

So yeah, 1000:1 dividers for 1kV (actually up to 40kV) are done (by Fluke); datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1816372.pdf claims +/-2% accuracy for DC. Even has fan/user videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXq4FCQ0C38 You can actually buy much more accurate ones (up to 0.01%) from places like [Ross Eng.](http://www.rossengineeringcorp.com/products/measurement/hv-voltage-dividers/hv-voltage-dividers-detailed-info.html), but I suspect they cost accordingly.